# iOS enterprise account for distribution

Tags: ios, enterprise, provisioning-profile, adhoc

A client wants to use their iOS enterprise account to distribute an app to their clients at event.
They don't want to publish the app to the AppStore, just have people go to a web page and get the app through the page.
I think it can be achieved with their enterprise account but is that in compliance with Apple's guidelines?
I could not find the answer to that.
Thanks!

Comment: No, this is a blatant violation.  You are only allowed to distribute to your employees.

Comment: When you say "clients at event" it implies to me that the people they want to get the app are from different companies, and not directly affiliated with your client. Legality aside, to allow that to happen from a purely technical point of view you have to get the device UUIDs from each person that wants the app, in advance of the event. I suspect this is going to be impractical in real life conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved, but it's not compliant with Apple's Enterprise Developer Account rules.

Even though you can do that (you just compile the app using the Enterprise certificate+provisioning profile), Apple's Enterprise Developer Account doesn't allow you to distribute the app for others that are not employees for the company. It's not an explicit information, but I have already talked to Apple through support and by phone and that's the official answer.

Comment: It most definitely *is* an explicit violation of terms.https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html

Comment: Yeah, but this link doesn't point to "the terms", legally speaking.

Comment: If it weren't a violation of the legal terms, then the questions on this page would not be answered in the way that they are.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll let my client know that although technically doable, this is against Apple's rule. After that, his call.